# Round y-axis values: Dojo Chart vs Chart.js

Tags: charts, dojo, dojox.charting

I am using Dojo Charts to create some line graphs, and this is how the chart looks,

this id chartData: 0,0,0,0,65,223

[image]

And when I create the graph using Chart.js, this is how it is rendered

[image]

Ignore the x-axis and other things, If we look at the y-axis, the values are rounded in chart.js, looks much nicer when compared to dojo charts.
Is there an option to achieve the same in dojo charts?

Answer (score 0):

Try adjusting `majorTickStep`, or optionally also set `minorTickMarks` to `true` and adjust `minorTickStep` as well.

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.10/dojox/charting.html#enabling-and-disabling-tick-marks and "Axis Stepping" two sections later.

Comment: yes, tried that, so there is no option in dojo which handles this itself, right?